# Persistent Dark mode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a switch that toggles dark mode on my website. I want it to be persistent when I open another page. This is my orginal code to toggle it:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=theme]");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    trans();
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
  } else {
    trans();
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
  }
});

let trans = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("transition");
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("transition");
  }, 1000);
};
```

However, i'm now trying to use local storage to make the change persistent on other webpages but this is not happening. It doesn't even toggle the dark theme anymore. Where am I going wrong and what should I change? I've searched around the site but no one is really doing it like i'm doing it. I'm new to JS so I want to understand what's going wrong before I pick up another solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=theme]");

var theme;
if (localStorage.getItem("data-theme")) {
  theme = localStorage.getItem("data-theme");
  trans();
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
} else {
  theme = "light";
  localStorage.setItem("data-theme", theme);
}
checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    trans();
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    theme = "dark";
    localStorage.setItem("data-theme", theme);
  } else {
    trans();
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    theme = "light";
    localStorage.setItem("data-theme", theme);
  }
});

let trans = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("transition");
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("transition");
  }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: localStorage items should persist if the pages all share the same protocol, domain and port: [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin)  If you do `console.log(theme)` on the second page after doing `theme = localStorage.getItem("data-theme")`, does it show the value?

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? If you define tran with this notation (```let trans =() => {...}```) the order is important. You can move the definition on top or use function notation (```function trans () {...}```)

Comment: @ATD yes it does. It shows "dark" but then I also get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'trans' before initialization` on the line "trans()' right below it

Comment: @dna console shows Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'trans' before initialization but it returns the value if i add `console.log(theme)`

Comment: Then it's likely that @carlo_webber124 is right - it's just the order of the code and, perhaps, where it is (eg, in HEAD or in BODY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using css variables, you could just change the variable values.

```js
function changecolour() {
  let c = document.getElementById("pickbackground").value;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--mystyle", c);

}
```

```css
:root {
  --mystyle:green;
}

span {
  background-color:var(--mystyle);
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<span>This is some text</span>
<br>
<hr>

<select id="pickbackground" onclick="changecolour();">
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

And, you can still use your localstorage code to save their selection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code below would work. You should initialize `trans` variable before you use it.

```
let trans = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("transition");
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("transition");
  }, 1000);
};

var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=theme]");

var theme;
if (localStorage.getItem("data-theme")) {
  theme = localStorage.getItem("data-theme");
  trans();
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
} else {
  theme = "light";
  localStorage.setItem("data-theme", theme);
}
checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    trans();
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    theme = "dark";
    localStorage.setItem("data-theme", theme);
  } else {
    trans();
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
    theme = "light";
    localStorage.setItem("data-theme", theme);
  }
});
```

Comment: I see. How come the first one worked though? As in to toggle the theme?

Comment: Either this is part of a function block that we are not seeing in full, or it may be in a `script` tag in the middle of a page and some of the elements are above that and others below it?

Comment: @carlo_webber124 i think it is because the `trans` variable called on in a callback method which wasn’t executed yet. When the callback gets executed , the function  was already  assigned in the memory so no error was thrown.

Comment: for instance: 
`let someFunc = () => logSmth();

let logSmth = () => console.log('log it');

someFunc()`

Comment: @ATD that was the entire function block. I had put the script tag as the last one before closing `body` tag. I think @Ahmet's comment below yours is why.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage saves key/value pairs based on your website's origin.
If your app is using multiple origins then you'll have to manage the key/value pairs every time you switch origin. If this is the case then you should consider saving this info in your back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I have already done this exact thing on another site. I threw together a minimal example below. The snippet below does not utilize the code for your intended purpose. Please see the full source code at the bottom of this post.

```js
const toggleTheme = () => {
  // Theme toggle button.
  const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

  function switchTheme(e) {
    let darkModeEnabled = e.target.checked;
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', darkModeEnabled ? 'dark' : 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', darkModeEnabled ? 'dark' : 'light');
  }
  toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

  // Restore theme state.
  const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;
  if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
      toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
  }
}

toggleTheme();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; }

:root {
  --foreground-color: #000;
  --background-color: #FFF;
  --link-color: #07D;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--foreground-color);
}

a, a:visited {
  color: var(--link-color);
}

h1, nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

header input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}

/** Dark theme */
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --foreground-color: #EEE;
  --background-color: #111;
  --link-color: #5AF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="theme-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
<section>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

### Full source code

#### js/script.js

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  toggleTheme();
});

const toggleTheme = () => {
  // Theme toggle button.
  const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
  function switchTheme(e) {
    let darkModeEnabled = e.target.checked;
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', darkModeEnabled ? 'dark' : 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', darkModeEnabled ? 'dark' : 'light');
  }
  toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

  // Restore theme state.
  const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;
  if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
      toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

#### css/default.css

```css
:root {
  --foreground-color: #000;
  --background-color: #FFF;
  --link-color: #07D;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--foreground-color);
}

a, a:visited {
  color: var(--link-color);
}

h1,
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

header input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

#### css/dark.css

```css
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --foreground-color: #EEE;
  --background-color: #111;
  --link-color: #5AF;
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="theme-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="./about.html">About</a>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### about.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>About</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="theme-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="./about.html">About</a>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <h1>About</h1>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps with my understanding