# How to animate text via CSS with vertically centered anchor point

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple JS script which listens to keyboard input and displays, at a random position, a short animation of every typed letter fading out and getting smaller.

```
'use strict'
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const ignoreKeys = [
    'Alt', 'Shift', 'Control', 'CapsLock', 'Tab', 'Backspace', 'Escape', 'Meta',
    'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown'
]

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (!ignoreKeys.includes(e.key)) {
        // Values 400 & 200 keep the div completely inside the window
        const maxHeight = window.innerHeight - 400
        const maxWidth = window.innerWidth - 200

        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.className = 'anim'
        div.textContent = e.key
        div.style.top = getRandomInt(0, maxHeight) + 'px'
        div.style.left = getRandomInt(0, maxWidth) + 'px'
        body.append(div)

        setTimeout(function() { div.remove() }, 3000)
    }
})

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

```
.anim {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0%;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 100%; font-size: 300px;}
    100% { opacity: 0%; font-size: 100px;}
}
```

By animating the `font-size` property, each letter gets smaller. However, since its "anchor point" is the top of the div, the visible effect is a letter getting smaller and moving slightly upwards. I would like each letter to shrink towards the vertical center of the `div` instead.

I can calculate the center the `div` easily and add the proper `top` coordinate to the `@keyframe` property, but I don't know how to modify that property in JS, individually for each `div`. Is this possible at all via CSS? Or should I rewrite the whole thing in pure JS?

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align:middle;` in the css?  Alternatively, you could add padding-top to your keyframes settings and increase it as the font-size decreases.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `vertical-align`, it doesn't change the result because reducing the `font-size` always makes the vertical center of the typeface move upwards (as it should). I would only like to be able to add, via JS, an individual `top` property to the `100%` keyframe so that the character moves towards the proper coordinate, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: As you are randomly placing the divs, you can't really specify individual top values for one css transition.  Adding padding-top would achieve the same thing, though, as that would just push the text down.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a hard-coded `padding-top` (or `margin-top`, rather) to the `100%` property helps, but since it's fixed it doesn't take into account the actual starting size of the typeface (which is fixed in my example but which needs to be randomised). This is why I'd like to apply it after a calculation of the actual `div` size. Also, it has the strange side-effect of making the character "vibrate" slightly as they fade away.

Comment: You would need to know the height of every single character to do that.  For example, the middle of "E" is higher than the middle of "e".  You can't vertically centre individual characters based on the character itself, only the font.  The only way around that, that I can think of now, is to have images instead - each image showing the text properly centered horizontally and vertically within the image box.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I was hoping to get by with an approximation. But suppose I use images – which I can't, really – even then I would need to make each of them move, based on its current position, towards a different `top` position (which would be something like `currentTop + (startHeight-endHeight) / 2`), and I still don't know how I could modify the `100%` keyframe individually for each image.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to adjust the div's top value at all.  As there is no border or anything else displayed for the DIV tag itself - just the letter within it - you can adjust either the margin, the border and/or the padding to achieve the same effect as increasing the top value for the DIV.  As each of these can be handled within the css transition, you could do something like:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    const body = document.querySelector('body')
    const ignoreKeys = [
        'Alt', 'Shift', 'Control', 'CapsLock', 'Tab', 'Backspace', 'Escape', 'Meta',
        'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown'
    ]
    if (!ignoreKeys.includes(e.key)) {
        // Values 400 & 200 keep the div completely inside the window
        const maxHeight = window.innerHeight - 400
        const maxWidth = window.innerWidth - 200
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.className = 'anim'
        div.textContent = e.key;
        div.style.top = getRandomInt(0, maxHeight) + 'px'
        div.style.left = getRandomInt(0, maxWidth) + 'px'
        body.append(div)

        setTimeout(function() { div.remove() }, 3000)
    }
})
```

```css
.anim {
  display:block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width:200px;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  margin:0px;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity:1; font-size: 300px;}
    100% { opacity:0; font-size: 100px; margin-top:100px;}
}
```

The initial state of the DIV is with margin:0px.  Adding a margin-top setting to the keyframes css, increases this from 0 to 100 during the transition.  The effect of that is to push the DIV down - and, as noted above, as nothing is being displayed for the DIV itself, the user will not see it move.  Note that I have fixed the width of the DIV at 200px so ensure that everything is always centered horizontally - otherwise the DIV width is based on the width of the character, so would change during transition and the character would move to the left as the centre line changes.  I've moved some of the code around to make it easier to test - but the only actual change is in the CSS styling.  Also note that opacity is a value from 0 to 1, so should not be shown as a percentage.

**UPDATE**

Have a look at the following snippet.  I think that it may be possible to have random font sizes AND random positions using `transform` rather than `animate`.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}

const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");

function zoomOUT(){
  let d = document.getElementById("test");
  d.classList.remove("zoomIN");
  d.classList.add("zoomOUT");
}

function zoomIN(){
  let d = document.getElementById("test");
  let dletter = document.getElementById("testletter");
  let t = getRandomInt(20, 60) * 10;
  let l = getRandomInt(20, 100) * 10;
  let fs = getRandomInt(10, 20) * 10;
  dletter.innerHTML = letters[getRandomInt(0, 61)];
  d.style.top = t + "px";
  d.style.left = l + "px";
  d.style.fontSize = fs + "%";
  d.classList.remove("zoomOUT");
  d.classList.add("zoomIN");
}
```

```css
#test {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.zoomIN {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(3);
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.zoomOUT {
  opacity:0.5;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: transform 3s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoomOUT();" z-index=1>Play</button><button onclick="zoomIN();" z-index=1>Restart</button>

<div id="test" class="zoomIN" style="top:300px; left:300px;" z-index=0><div id="testletter" style="font-size:600%; width:100%; height:100%">A</div></div>
```

Transform seems to keep things in the same place, so there is no need to adjust any top/margin/border/padding settings at all.  In fact, the only things that change are the font-size (using `scale(..)`) and opacity.  The size of the font is determined by the code.  Note that this requires the character to be in a div within a div.  This is just a test, but should give you enough to convert things into your code requirements.

Comment: Thank you. This works, although it wouldn't if the initial `font-size` were randomised (as I mentioned in the comments above), because the `margin-top` is a fixed value (100px in your example). If the starting `font-size` is different, the character would still move vertically. Is there no way to set the destination keyframe's `margin-top` dynamically?

Comment: The only way you can dynamically change anything in css is to use css variables - see [css variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64047834/persistent-dark-mode-in-javascript).  However, that would affect ALL characters from that point on - you can't set it for individual characters if there are going to be more than one on screen at a time.  You could have multiple css's for each size - and your code could pick one randomly - though, you would probably want to limit the sizes available as you would have to have one css style/@keyframes pair for each size.

Comment: I've updated my Answer with a possible solution.  Run the snippet in Full Page mode to get the full effect.